# How to use WITH AS in SELECT (with an alias)

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to nest **Query 1** inside another query (**Query 2**) using `WITH AS` but there may be some conflict with the alias `q` I'm using.
I can use **Query 1** after `FROM` in **Query 2** but I want to know if there's any chance I could use `WITH AS` here. Thank you so much!

**Table `topups`**

```
 id_user |    date    | promo_ind 
---------+------------+----------
       1 | 2017-06-20 | N        
       1 | 2017-05-20 | N        
       1 | 2017-04-20 | Y        
       1 | 2017-03-20 | Y         
       1 | 2017-02-20 | N
```

**Query 1**

```
SELECT *,
        (SELECT max(date)
         FROM topups q2 
         WHERE id_user = q.id_user AND 
               q2.promo_ind = 'Y' AND 
               q.date > q2.date) AS last_promo_start
FROM topups q ORDER BY date DESC;
```

**Result of Query 1**

```
 id_user |    date    | promo_ind |last_promo_start
---------+------------+-----------+----------------
       1 | 2017-06-20 | N         | 2017-04-20
       1 | 2017-05-20 | N         | 2017-04-20
       1 | 2017-04-20 | Y         | 2017-03-20
       1 | 2017-03-20 | Y         |    NULL
       1 | 2017-02-20 | N         |    NULL
```

**Query 2**

```
WITH table_2 AS
    (SELECT *,
        (SELECT max(date)
         FROM topups q2 
         WHERE id_user = q.id_user AND 
               q2.promo_ind = 'Y' AND 
               q.date > q2.date) AS last_promo_start
    FROM topups q)

SELECT id_user,
        date, 
        promo_ind, 
        
        (CASE WHEN last_promo_start + 28 < date 
            THEN (CASE WHEN promo_ind LIKE 'Y'
                    THEN date
                    ELSE NULL
                  END)
            ELSE last_promo_start
         END
         ) AS promo_start, 
        
        (CASE WHEN last_promo_start + 28 < date 
            THEN (CASE WHEN promo_ind LIKE 'Y'
                    THEN date + 28
                    ELSE NULL
                  END)
            ELSE (CASE WHEN promo_ind LIKE 'Y'
                    THEN last_promo_start + 28 + 28
                    ELSE last_promo_start + 28
                  END)
         END
         ) AS promo_end
         
FROM table_2
ORDER BY id_user, date DESC;
```

**Expected result of Query 2**

```
 id_user |    date    | promo_ind | promo_start | promo_end 
---------+------------+-----------+-------------+-----------
       1 | 2017-06-20 | N         |    NULL     |   NULL
       1 | 2017-05-20 | N         |    NULL     |   NULL
       1 | 2017-04-20 | Y         | 2017-04-20  | 2017-05-18
       1 | 2017-03-20 | Y         | 2017-03-20  | 2017-04-17
       1 | 2017-02-20 | N         |    NULL     |   NULL
```

Comment: Your CTE (With statement) looks fine. It's your CASE Expression logic that is probably not giving you the results you want. For instance, If the last_promo_start date is NOT 28 days from the record date, then it will give you `last_promo_start` date as your `promo_start`. BUT... You seem to want it to be NULL. What I can't discern from your code though is that if you want it to be NULL because it's `promo_ind="N"` or if you want NULL because the `last_promo_start` date was more than 28 days ago. Can you clarify how you are getting to your "Expected results"?

Comment: @JNevill Thank you! So the requirement is: If `promo_ind` customer will get a free credit for 28 calendar days immediately following the `date` of that top-up. The free credit period may be effectively prolonged multiple times.